# What visa does a Filipino need to visit New Zealand for two weeks from Australia?

Tags: visas, filipino-citizens, new-zealand

I have an Australian tourist visa 9 months and am a Filipino citizen. I am currently in Australia and wish to travel to New Zealand for two weeks.

What visa would I need and best way to apply?

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy [SkyTeam](https://www.skyteam.com/en/flights-and-destinations/visa-and-health/):

> New Zealand - Destination Passport
>
> Passport required.
>
> Document validity rules:
>
> Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to nationals
>   of Philippines must be valid for a minimum of 1 month beyond the
>   period of intended stay. The following regulations apply to
>   children/minors:
>
> Minors entering New Zealand may be included in the passport of the
>   parent, who is traveling with them. Important:
>
> Passengers with an APEC Business Travel Card must travel with a
>   passport. The passport number and nationality must match those stated
>   on the card.
>
> Type: Notice New Zealand - Destination Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> Passengers with an APEC Business Travel Card valid for travel to "NZL"
>   if traveling on business for a maximum stay of 3 months. The card is
>   valid for the countries listed on the back of the card. Visa issuance:
>
> New Zealand issues both printed visa labels and label-less visas.
>   Printed visa labels are inserted into a passport or travel document.
>   There is no physical evidence of a label-less visa in the passport or
>   travel document but all passengers must carry a printed visa approval
>   letter that confirms the details of their visa. The New Zealand visa
>   record is held in Immigration New Zealand's systems and authority to
>   board should be verified using the NZ APP system. Airlines not
>   connected to NZ APP that carry a passenger on an earlier leg of their
>   journey, can use TIETACNZ, or view the printed visa label or the visa
>   approval letter to identify any travel conditions, such as whether the
>   person is exempt from the requirement to hold a return/onward ticket.
>   Additional information:
>
> Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to cover their
>   stay. The amount of funds needed is NZD 1,000.- per person per month
>   of stay or NZD 400.- if accommodation has been prepaid. Evidence of
>   funds may be in the form of cash, traveler's cheques, bank drafts,
>   letters of credit or the following credit cards: Diners Club, American
>   Express, Bankcard, Mastercard and Visa. If Visa label contains "Funds
>   Waived", evidence of sufficient funds is not required.
>
> Visitors are required to hold documents for their next destination.
>
> Important:
>
> Visitors holding a visa that specifies the requirement to hold an
>   outward ticket must hold return/onward tickets.
>
> Exempt are holders of authorization issued by New Zealand?s
>   immigration authorities waiving the return ticket requirement.

The easiets way to apply may be [online](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/about-visa/visitor-visa#https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/tools-and-information/general-information/eligible-to-apply-online/slider).